# Is it a good practice to make most of the methods of a class return instance of the class?

Tags: java

Is there any performance or design issues if we make all the methods of a class (methods that would normally return void) return the instance of the class (or a subclass)?

**Edit**: I wasn't thinking about the builder pattern, actually. I was just exploring fluent api design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with cybersam it's a good practice (for the right circumstances), but I don't think this is the original Builder Pattern. I believe it's called the [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). [Builder patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) aren't required to return an instance of the class after every call.

Answer (score 7):

This is actually a good practice called the "Builder Pattern". [Here is a JavaWorld article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html) that discusses it.

Answer (score 0):

This also goes by the name " Fluent API". See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface